# Flutter PWA color barra navegación del explorador

Tags: flutter, pwa

Tengo una plataforma que esta disponible como PWA.
Quiero que el color de la barra de navegación del explorador donde se abre, cambie con el sistema cuando se cambia el dark Mode o light Mode.

Estas son las pantallas de safari, pero en chrome es el caso similar.

Light mode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dark mode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    cardTheme: CardTheme(shape: Curvas.bordersA10),
    dialogTheme: DialogTheme(shape: Curvas.bordersA10),
    primaryColor: primaryColor,
    primaryColorLight: Colors.black45,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primary: Colors.blue[400],
      onPrimary: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
      secondary: Colors.blue[400],
      onSecondary: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
      error: Color(0xFFF32424),
      onError: Color(0xFFF32424),
      background: primaryColor,
      onBackground: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
      surface: Colors.blue[400],
      onSurface: Colors.black38,
    ),
  ),

ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    cardTheme: CardTheme(shape: Curvas.bordersA10),
    dialogTheme: DialogTheme(shape: Curvas.bordersA10),
    primaryColor: primaryColor,
    primaryColorDark: Colors.grey[700],
    colorScheme: ColorScheme(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      primary: Colors.blue[700],
      onPrimary: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
      secondary: Colors.blue[700],
      onSecondary: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
      error: Color(0xFFF32424),
      onError: Color(0xFFF32424),
      background: Colors.grey[700],
      onBackground: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
      surface: Colors.blue[700],
      onSurface: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué es lo que no sabes hacer? ¿Qué has intentado? ?_?

Comment: @Manuel el color de la barra de navegación del explorador, no cambia con el modo oscuro del sistema, se queda en gris, cuando la PWA, tiene el color azul.

Comment: Podrías probar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317046/how-to-change-chrome-header-color-in-flutter-web